# How to use the php define properly

Tags: php, path, constants, realpath

I have this line of php code that sets the main folder of my site as the storage folder. How can I change this to the 'tmp' folder?

```
define('COOKIELOCAL', str_replace('\\', '/', realpath('./')).'/');
```

For example mysite.com, I want the files stay in mysite.com/tmp so I can clear this folder using a cron tab, any tips?

In other words what I need is to save the temp files created using this path in the 'tmp' folder instead the root one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why str_replace is being used like it is, but the following should work, while modifying the least from the code you originally posted:

```
define('COOKIELOCAL', str_replace('\\', '/', realpath('./tmp')).'/');
```

This would also work:

```
define('COOKIELOCAL', realpath('./tmp').'/');
```

Or, as has been suggested in another post:

```
define('COOKIELOCAL', './tmp/');
```

Comment: PERFECT thats all i need

Answer (score 0):

It depends how `COOKIELOCAL` is ultimately being used, but the following should achieve what you need:

```
define('COOKIELOCAL', './tmp/');
```

Comment: Did you mean './tmp/' ?

Comment: This will set it to /tmp and not his configured tmp ;)

Comment: @Anyone > ' i want the files stay in **mysite.com/tmp**'

Comment: define('COOKIELOCAL', __ DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR . 'tmp'); with __DIR, parsing makes it bold instead: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: No need to use constants there. It's pretty clear from his original post that he's using Linux-style separators ;)

Comment: I know, even on windows the '/' will work. It's just a courtesy